# How to find $\omega^7$ and $\omega^6$ from $\omega^5+1=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

---

I did the first parts :

$$\omega= (\cos \pi + i \sin \pi)^\frac{1}{5} \implies \omega^5 = \cos \pi + i \sin \pi=-1$$

---

$\omega=-1$ is a root so :

$$\omega^5-1= (\omega+1) (\omega^4-\omega^3+\omega^2-\omega+1)=0$$

$$\omega^4-\omega^3+\omega^2-\omega=-1$$

---

$$\omega-\omega^4=\cos \frac{\pi}{5} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{5} - (\cos \frac{4\pi}{5} + i \sin \frac{4\pi}{5})$$

$$\omega-\omega^4=\cos \frac{\pi}{5} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{5} - (-\cos \frac{\pi}{5} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{5})$$

$$\omega-\omega^4= 2 \cos \frac{\pi}{5}$$

Did similar method for $\omega^3-\omega^2$ and got the desired result.

---

For this part I only know the first part which is:

$$\cos \frac{\pi}{5} + \cos \frac{3\pi}{5}$$

$$2\cos {\pi}{5} + 2\cos \frac{3\pi}{5}=\omega-\omega^4+\omega^3-\omega^2=1$$

$$\cos \frac{\pi}{5} + \cos \frac{3\pi}{5}=\frac{1}{2}$$

---

$$\cos \frac{\pi}{5} \cos \frac{3\pi}{5} = \frac{1}{4} (\omega-\omega^4)(\omega^3-\omega^2)$$

$$\frac{1}{4} (\omega^4-\omega^3-\omega^7+\omega^6)$$

**How do I find $\omega^7$ and $\omega^6$** ???? please help.

---

*Also I would love if I receive support for the last part too, I don't know how  to make a quadratic equation*

Comment: If anyone knows a superb awesome book or some online reference to these types of complex number chapters (not tooo extreme or not too elementary) let me know. Because Im super weak in complex numbers and I struggle a lot

Comment: Apply de Moivre's Theorem to find $w^7$ and $w^6$. It's straightforward.

Comment: $w^5=-1$, so $w^7=-w^2$, $w^6=-w$

Comment: @daOnlyBG Im afraid I don't think it's possible.

Comment: If already $w^5+1=0$ then $w^6+w=0$ so $w^6=-w.$ Similarly $w^7+w^2=0$ so $w^7=-w^2.$ [Just saw Exodd gave same in slightly older comment]

Comment: @Exodd WOW WOW WOW :O HOW DID YOU THINK IN SUCH A SHORT TIME :o

Comment: @TheArtist coffeemath's solution is best, but I'm curious- why don't you think it's possible?

Comment: @TheArtist : The letter $\omega$ is (as you ought to expect) available in MathJax, and is coded just the way you would expect.  You don't need to substitute the letter $w$ for it. (I changed it.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @coffeemath Thank you very much :) I understood :D

Comment: @daOnlyBG , because we found the 5th root of unity, so the highest power that can be obtained (highest root) is $\omega^5$ so that's why I don't think can apply de moivre

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you very much for the edit :)

Comment: @TheArtist They're gonna ban me for this, but I can't resist http://new2.fjcdn.com/thumbnails/comments/5167709+_142e0e3ffa02fbfc098d642cd417f057.jpg

Comment: Do YOURL know a superb book so that I can become an expert in complex numbers (to this standard) , I ask many complex numbers questions on this site. Weakest point of me

Comment: @TheArtist no, you can still use the theorem. But again, coffeemath's solution is more clever.

Comment: @daOnlyBG Really? :) Il give it a try :) Do you know any book? :)

Comment: A very straightforward and easy-to-use book is Dennis Zill's *Complex Analysis: a First Course with Applications.*

Comment: @daOnlyBG Thank you very much :) Im going to check this out :)

Comment: @Exodd okay :p Please? :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the quadratic equation part, note that if $(x-a)(x-b)=0$ the roots of the equation are $a$ and $b$.

Expand the brackets and you get the equation $x^2-(a+b)x+ab=0$ with roots $a$ and $b$.

This means that if you know the sum of the roots $a+b$ and the product of the roots $ab$, you can write down a quadratic equation which has the roots $a$ and $b$. This is what your question is leading you through.

Comment: (+1) Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh :D THANKKSSSSSSSS :D UNDERSTOOOD :D

Answer (score 2):

Since $\omega^5+1=0$, you have that $\omega^5=-1$, so $\omega^6=\omega^5\cdot\omega=-\omega$ etc.

For the quadratic equation, use that $(x-a)(x-b)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab$, let $a=\frac{1}{2}(\omega-\omega^4)=\cos(\pi/5)$ and $b=\frac{1}{2}(\omega^3-\omega^2)$. You calculated values for $a+b$ and $ab$ just beforehand, so you have the quadratic equation (namely $x^2-x-1$).